# Inserting php code into html- code truncated

Tags: php, html, forms

Trying to add Recaptcha to my php form, I started off with the example php code provided by Google. I inserted the following code, into form1.php:

```
<html>
<body>

 <h3>You can use the following form to contact the author:</h3>

<form action="send1.php" method="post" name="contactform">

<table width="450px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" maxlength="50" name="first_name" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="last_name">Last Name *</label></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" maxlength="50" name="last_name" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="email">Email Address *</label></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" maxlength="80" name="email" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" maxlength="30" name="telephone" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="comments">Comments *</label></td>
<td valign="top"><textarea cols="30" maxlength="1000" name="comments" rows="6"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">
<?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "GOkj44zG4SZKeo3PYMTmPYySzp7JPdq4";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of seeing a captcha image, I found that even the Submit button disappeared. On viewing the source code from browser, I found that the code was truncated after the line `<td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">`. From the beginning of the php code, nothing was displayed on the page.

Is this not the proper way to insert php code into html? Why is the html code truncated at the beginning of php code?

Comment: are you sure that recaptchalib.php is in the same directory as this form1.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *is* the proper way.

But if you didn't download or install all files correctly, there might be an error. Such an error may halt script execution immediately, so that also blocks the static html which is outputted after the script.

The syntax of the script seems correct, and the fact that apparently something has *tried* to run it suggests that PHP is set up as well. So my guess is that recaptchalib.php cannot be found, or it includes other files that cannot be found.

If you don't get any error in your output, you may want to check your error logs, or enable error output, so you can get a better view of what is going on.

Comment: That's what's odd. I've rechecked and verified that the file recaptchalib.php exists in the same directory, and has the correct filename. I even tried adding the full path in the require_once function. recaptchalib.php is invoked when I try running it directly by entering its url.

Comment: Checked the doc again, and apparently you need only that one file. Still, including it could cause the problem somehow, but without a proper error message, it'll be guessing.

Comment: I enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');`. I also looked at apache log. It showed just `[06/Jul/2013:21:51:15 +0400] "GET /phpscripts/form1 HTTP/1.1" 200 395 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"`, which I presume means there were no errors shown? I even executed it via `php form1.php` from bash. Nada.

Comment: Very odd. I'm sorry, I don't have a clou.

Comment: Could it be some parameter defined in php.ini?